# How to make connection with AWS EC2 instance and locate the hosted files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using a AWS console which show a running instance but when I check the storage in S3 there are no files in it. I have checked all the other storage options but unable to find any files. I need to check that which website is hosted on this instance. What can i do?

Moreover, I do not have .pem of the instance

I am working on a client website and we have a doubt that one of our website is hosted on AWS. We want to migrate that website  from AWS to another host.

Please guide what is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can setup and use [session manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) to login to the instance without private ssh keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon EC2 uses Elastic Block Store (EBS) volumes for its file system, not S3. So if the web site is hosted by an EC2 instance, the files will most likely be stored on an EBS volume. To get access, you will probably need to log in to the instance using SSH or the [AWS Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/session-manager.html). Alternatively, you can try and [attach the volume to a different EC2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html) that you have access to.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly S3 is for object storage, the instance runs off block storage using EBS and is where the file structure is located. Unless a job exists to manually copy content to S3 you will not find it there.

There are a few options you can perform to gain access:

- You can try connecting using [Sessions Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) assuming that the [SSM Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html) is running on the host.
- You can try using [instance connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Connect-using-EC2-Instance-Connect.html) if it is setup, this will allow you to [use an SSH terminal by specifying a temporary pem](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2-instance-connect/send-ssh-public-key.html).
- You can create an AMI of the server and then launch a new instance from this AMI (the server will be running as if it is the server that you took the AMI from so be aware services will be running).
- You can take a EBS snapshot of the server and attempt to launch a new volume from this. You would then mount it to a host.

Be aware that if this is a Windows host, connecting via regular RDP will require the Windows password of the host. If this is the case you will need to follow [these instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-admin-password/).